# How to solve design database issue that violates the normalizaton rule?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `Orders` that contains available orders and `ExecutorsOfferOffers` that contains offers by concrete user for specific order:

[image: Example image tables]

The order can be in four statuses: accepted, canceled, finished. Inside `ExecutorsOfferOffers` we have history of rows when user can accept, reject and complete the order (field status).

At the same time table `Orders` also has status field to show the current status of order. I confused how to be, move `executor_id` as external key to `Orders` table among `status`. Or store them in `ExecutorsOfferOffers`. And retrieve the status the order by selecting onw row ordered by id from `ExecutorsOfferOffers`.

In this case I faced with problem when user can accept, then cancel order (insert two rows in `ExecutorsOfferOffers` with different statuses).

Comment: This may be a reasonable case to violate normalization. Getting the most recent status from `ExecutorsOfferOffers` can be expensive, so it's OK to keep that in `Order`. You could use a trigger to keep it in sync.

Comment: `ExecutorsOfferOffers` is missing a timestamp, which one is the latest one? Don't trust the ID to be consecutive.

Comment: How do you think is it good idea to devide ExecutorsOfferOffers on two table: SelectedExecutorsOfferOrders where to store who have participation and ExecutorsOfferOrderStatuses where to store history of order states, user accpeted, canceled or completed the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly:

- `ExecutorsOrderOffers` contains the history of user requests to change the status of the order.
- `Orders` contains the current status of the order.
- One Order can have many ExecutorsOrderOffers.

## They're not recording the same data.

This information is not necessarily the same. Just because a User *requested* an order be cancelled does not mean it *is* cancelled; someone might need to make a phone call or an API might need to be contacted. Perhaps you should leave the status decoupled.

This leaves more flexibility for the business logic to determine the relationship between ExecutorsOrderOffers and Orders.

## Use a join table to record the Order status.

Status flags get messy. You have to remember to add them to every where clause, and they make indexing complicated. Instead, consider using a join table to record the status of an order.

```
-- One for each status.
create table AcceptedOrders (
  Order_Id int not null
    foreign key(Order_Id) references Orders(Id)
);
```

## Add a timestamp to ExecutorsOrderOffers.

IDs are not a surrogate for timestamps, and you're probably going to want to know when a user made a change; add a Created_At timestamp.

## Add an index on ExecutorsOrderOffers(Created_At, Orders_ID)

Index Created_At with Orders_ID in that order. This will cover searches and `order by` for `Created_At` as well as when combined with an Orders_ID.

The foreign key index already covers search by Orders_ID alone.

Now you can efficiently look up the latest user request to change the status of an order.

Comment: I did not get about `AcceptedOrders`, should I create `CanceledOrders` and `CompletedOrders`

Comment: @Gogol Yes, one for each status. Then instead of checking the status flag, you join with the appropriate table. The downside is you can't ensure an Order has only one status. An alternative is to [partition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html) Orders on Status, this makes searching by status effectively free.

Comment: does it make sense to have three tables with status? With only two fields:  order_id, status and how to set constrain for statud if it is completed?